# Filtering a long list with search bar is very slow

Tags: list, filter, swiftui, searchbar

I have a list with up to 100 items. While filtering the list with a searchbar it takes some time for every letter.
How can I speed up the search?
One possible solution is to filter only after click the search button on the keyboard.

````
        
     
            VStack {
                SearchBar(text: $searchTerm, placeholder: "Suche")
            }
            
         
                List {
                    
                    ForEach(gesetzestextTEMPO.filter {
                        self.searchTerm.isEmpty ? true : $0.titel1.localizedCaseInsensitiveContains(searchTerm)
                            || $0.titel1.localizedCaseInsensitiveContains(searchTerm)
                            || $0.artikel.localizedCaseInsensitiveContains(searchTerm)
                            || $0.marginale.localizedCaseInsensitiveContains(searchTerm)
                            || $0.absatz0.localizedCaseInsensitiveContains(searchTerm)
                            || $0.absatz0litaz.localizedCaseInsensitiveContains(searchTerm)
                          
                        
                        })
                    { item in
                        Part13(gesetzestextTEMPO: item, searchTerm: self.$searchTerm)
                    }
                }```
````

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
List {
    // ...
}
.id(UUID())
```

as proposed here: [How to fix slow List updates in SwiftUI](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/articles/210/how-to-fix-slow-list-updates-in-swiftui)